# Installing .NET frmwk 1.1 after 2.0 and 3.5

Tags: .net-framework-version

I am currently running Windows 7 - 64bit, with .NET framework 2.0 and 3.5 installed. I have a customer that needs a program written for .NET 1.1. Visual Studio will not let me build for a target platform of .NET 1.1 unless it is installed. Can I install .NET 1.1 on my current system without messing anything up?

Answer (score 2):

Note that you will need to install Visual Studio 2003 if you want to target .NET Framework 1.1.

However, this version of Visual Studio is no longer officially supported on Windows 7. Best you go with a VM:

> **[Has anyone managed to get Visual Studio 2003 running on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879082/has-anyone-managed-to-get-visual-studio-2003-running-on-windows-7)**

In the long run you are best off migrating to at least .NET 2.0 runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have Win 7, [install XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) and install an earlier version of Visual Studio on there to compile to .NET 1.1.