# Visual Studio 2003 Cant use pdb file in both debug mode and release mode

Tags: c++, debugging, pdb-files, visual-studio-2003

I have a Visual Studio 2003 installed on a Windows7-64Bit. When I build a project in vs2003 it creates a pdb file. For example: for a project named SampleProject, it creates a SampleProject.pdb and when i try to rebuild it gives an error like:

fatal error C1033: cannot open program database 'd:....\SampleProject.pdb'

I can rebuild only if i close visual studio 2003 and delete pdb and let him regenerate a new one

Can u help please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Has anyone managed to get Visual Studio 2003 running on Windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879082/has-anyone-managed-to-get-visual-studio-2003-running-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

It's a known compatibility problem of Visual Studio 2003 on Windows Seven (another one is "Find All" blocking the whole application if you don't disable Aero themes).

It seems that the only solution to avoid restarting VS2003 every time is to unlock the PDB (with some unlocker-like application) and delete it; I even added it as an "External tool" with some keyboard shortcut. Sad thing that MS didn't even release a fix for it (and instead jumped through hoops to make VS 6.0 work on every Windows version).

---edit---

I knew it... there's [already a question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879082/has-anyone-managed-to-get-visual-studio-2003-running-on-windows-7) (whence I learned about the workaround).

Comment: Can u give an example of "unlocker-like" application or can u give a link to it please and how to set it as an external tool. Newbie alert!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1836771/214671 (I can't give you precise instructions about how to add it as an external tool because I am currently on a Linux machine)

Answer (score 0):

I work on Windows 7 Professional 64bit and had the same issue with fatal error C1033 during compiling C++ project in VS2003 (with installed SP1). Setting application compatibility to Windows Vista (I tried also Vista SP2 succesfully) eliminated this problem.

Comment: this seems more like a comment than an answer