# Visual Studio 2003 on Windows 7: breakpoints only work SOMETIMES

Tags: breakpoints, visual-studio-2003, intermittent

Breakpoints are ignored (the red circles disappear as the program starts) around half the time I run my program, the other half of the time it works fine. Basically I have to quit my program and restart it if I notice the breakpoints disappear. Is there a better solution?

Comment: What language is this? Are you running optimized code or code in Release mode?

Comment: I am amazed VS2003 works at all on Windows 7.  Tried it elevated?

Comment: Yes, the better solution is to get Visual Studio 2013 Express and spend the time to convert your project(s).

Comment: You got a warning, "This program has known compatibility issues", when you installed it.  Now you know what they look like.  Well, some of them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Has anyone managed to get Visual Studio 2003 running on Windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879082/has-anyone-managed-to-get-visual-studio-2003-running-on-windows-7)

Comment: Dai - language is C, I'm not sure the definition of "optimized code" but I am running in Debug mode (as opposed to Release mode)

As for why I'm using VS 2003 on Windows 7, that's just how things are

Hans - I've unsuccessfully tried suggestions on that page including:
- running as Admin
- setting application compatibility to Windows Vista SP2 and WinXP SP3
- closing pdb file handles (it opens a new one each time not closing the old, but this seems unrelated to whether or not I can debug)

Answer (score 0):

You stated VS2003, are you sure you meant 2003 and not 2013?  Can you clarify the language (C#, VB?);  Also are you building a console app, windows, app, web, etc?

In all cases the breakpoints do work in VS Studio.  They can be unreachable if you are making edits to your program without restarting.  Or if you are changing code that is not re-compiled into the dll you are stepping into.

Comment: C, win32 project, not editting, just running and closing the program and it only hits breakpoints sometimes

Answer (score 0):

This seems to fix it:

-detach the process

-reattach it

Now it hits the breakpoints